# Create draggable edge point on imageView

Tags: android, image-resizing

I want to create a resize feature of my application but I cannot find a sample implementation of it. Many tutorials offers pinch to zoom.

My problem now is how to implement draggable edges to resize the image just like in ordinary image editor. Do you have any idea how to do this? Just like putting circles/points on the 4 corners of the ImageView like the sample image below.

[image]

Is it possible to use the crop library of android to have draggable image?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the control point, and handle all festure in this point

last month i develop a Android handwritting note app. In this app, i inherit View, and control View.onDraw directly. I draw the image and all control indicator in onDraw, and handle screen touch within the scope of the screen.

This app isn't accomplished, it become a opensource project, you can see the source at https://bitbucket.org/gd920129/white-board/